# Запрет запуска в кроне задания если выполняется другое

Tags: php, cron

Ситуация следующая, имеется два скрипта поставленные в кроне:

1)Отправка уведомлений пользователям каждые 2 минуты.

2)Запись в таблицу уведомлений новых записей (в этом скрипе сначала записываются данные,а потом они правятся (необходимость такая)) каждый день в определенный час, например, в 7 часов утра.

Может случиться ситуация когда была внесена запись в таблицу уведомлений и не была изменена, но уже попала в выборку отправки. То есть отправится неправильный текст.

Как можно запретить выполнение скрипта 1, если выполняется скрипт 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ, первый скрипт при запуске создает файл, к примеру imbusy.txt а по окончании работы, удаляет его.

Во втором скрипте вначале работы можно написать примерно так:

```
//Ходим по циклу пока файл существует
while (file_exists("imbusy.txt"))
{
    sleep(30); //То есть ждем 30 секунд перед следующей проверкой
}
//Далее то что вам нужно сделать
```

Comment: если второй скрипт будет долго выполняться,то второй экземпляр первого скрипта может застигнуть первый и они будут работать с примерно и той же выборкой->уведомления буду дублироваться.но вариант не плохой-на заметку надо взять(для скриптов с большим таймаутом выполнения)))

Comment: Если есть такая вероятность, то пусть первый экземпляр первого скрипта, тоже как то помечает что он работает, и в этом скрипте добавить проверку, если первый экземпляр работает, то просто выходим.

Comment: ну да...в том же файле...спасибо=)